# Extend Javascript Form object with prototype

Tags: javascript, forms, prototype

Is there any chance to use prototype on a Form object, this is not working:

```
Form.prototype.myFunc=function()
{
  alert('OK!');
}
```

On the other hand, String objects are extendable, for example:

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
  return this.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
}
```

Comment: since there is no `Form` object - no, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you means `HTMLFormElement`, then it should be

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.myFunc=function() {
  alert('OK!');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no specification that requires DOM objects to implement any kind of inheritance, much less prototype inheritance. Having said that, many browsers do but it is not standardised or universally implemented.

You might like to read [What’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

In browsers that do implement a prototype inheritance scheme for DOM elements, you can try extending `HTMLFormElement.prototype` using something like:

```
if (typeof HTMLFormElement == 'object' && 
    typeof HTMLFormElement.prototype == 'object') {

    // extend HTMLFormElement.prototype

}
```

Note however that the behaviour of host objects is entirely implementation dependant. The above may do anything, including throw errors.